# React NextJS unable to upload a file through nextjs api at the same time as my form data 501 Not Implemented req.body undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, file-upload, next.js

I have a nextjs app with a form in which I give the user the option to upload a file at the same time as filling out their personal data. I am using Multer and in the next-connect middleware I am using, it has me set bodyParser to false. As I am collecting other data, I get an error 501 cannot implement saying `"error": "Sorry something Happened! Cannot destructure property 'firstName' of 'req.body' as it is undefined."`

I then resorted to another piece of middleware called multiparty which I am using in the addcv route of the nextjs api. I am still getting the same error. If anyone can help me sort out this issue, I would appreciate it. I don't understand why it is not possible to upload a file at the same time as the form data as I could do this in a normal nodejs app without issue.

Here are the relevant parts of the Form:

```
CVForm.jsx
import { useSubmitCV } from '../hooks/useSubmitCV';
function CVForm() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    cvfile: '',
    address: '',
    usEligible: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    zip: '',
    dob: '',
    description: '',
  });
  const [blockOneOpen, setBlockOneOpen] = useState(false);
  const [havecv, setHaveCv] = useState(false);
  const [haveNoCv, setHaveNoCv] = useState(false);
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Click Here To Start');

  const { submitcv, error, loading } = useSubmitCV();

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const onFileChange = (e) => {
    if (!cvfile) {
      setFormData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        cvfile: null,
      }));
    } else {
      setFormData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        cvfile: e.target.files[0],
      }));
    }
  };
const cvSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      formData.firstName === '' ||
      formData.lastName === '' ||
      formData.email === '' ||
      formData.phone === ''
    ) {
      toast.error('All Fields are required');
    } else {
      await submitcv(formData);
    }
    console.log(formData);
    setButtonClicked(!buttonClicked);
    setButtonText('Start Here');
  };
// JSX PORTION 
<label className='block mb-6 mt-6 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300'                       
  htmlFor='file_input'>Upload Resume
</label>
<input
className='block w-full text-sm text-white bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 cursor-pointer dark:text-white focus:outline-none dark:bg-[#00388d] dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-white'
id='cvfile'
type='file'
filename='cvfile'
name='cvfile'
onChange={onFileChange}
accept='.doc,.docx,.pdf,.odf' />
   <div className='mb-6 mt-6'>
      <button type='submit'className='w-full px-2 py-4 text-white bg-[#00388d] rounded-md  focus:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none'>
      Send Resume
     </button>
</div>
```

The Use Submit Hook useSubmitCV.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export const useSubmitCV = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);

  const router = useRouter();

  // const { dispatch } = useCVContext();

  const API_URL = '/api/cvs/addcv';

  const submitcv = async (formData) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('firstName', formData.firstName);
    form.append('lastName', formData.lastName);
    form.append('email', formData.email);
    form.append('phone', formData.phone);
    form.append('cvfile', formData.cvfile);
    form.append('fileUrl', formData.fileUrl);
    form.append('address', formData.address);
    form.append('city', formData.city);
    form.append('state', formData.state);
    form.append('zip', formData.zip);
    form.append('usEligible', formData.usEligible);
    form.append('dob', formData.dob);
    form.append('description', formData.description);

    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, form);
    if (response.data.message) {
      setError(response.data.message);
      toast.error(response.data.message);
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }
    toast.success('Resume Successfully Submitted');
    setLoading(false);
    router.push('/');
  };
  return { submitcv, loading, error };
};
```

The Middleware file middleware.js

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import multiparty from 'multiparty';

const middleware = nextConnect();

middleware.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  const form = new multiparty.Form();

  await form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    req.body = fields;
    req.files = files;
    next();
  });
});

export default middleware;
```

And Finally the addcv.js Route within the api route of nextjs

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import multer from 'multer';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import middleware from '../../../middleware/middleware';

import { File, Web3Storage } from 'web3.storage';

import CV from '../../../models/cvModel';

const w3storage = new Web3Storage({ token: process.env.WEB3_STORAGE_TOKEN });

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /doc|docx|pdf|odf/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb('Error: Documents Only!');
  }
}

const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', 'uploads'));
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, uuidv4() + '-' + file.originalname);
  },
  fileFilter: function (_req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
});

const maxSize = 3 * 1000 * 1000;

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: maxSize } });

const createCV = nextConnect({
  onError(error, req, res) {
    res
      .status(501)
      .json({ error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}` });
  },
  onNoMatch(req, res) {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  },
})
  .use(middleware)
  .use(upload.single('cvfile'))
  .post((req, res) => {
    // @desc Create a new cv
    // @route POST /api/cvs/addcv
    // @access Public

    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      phone,
      cvfile,
      address,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
      usEligible,
      dob,
      description,
    } = req.body;

    const fileUrl = req.file.filename;

    console.log(fileUrl);
    const bytes = fs.readFileSync(`${process.env.UPLOAD_PATH}/${fileUrl}`);
    const newFile = new File([bytes], fileUrl);
    const cid = w3storage.put([newFile]);
    const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', 'uploads', fileName);
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
      fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
    }
    const cv = CV.create({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      phone,
      cvfile,
      address,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
      usEligible,
      dob,
      description,
      fileUrl: `https://${cid}.ipfs.dweb.link/${fileName}`,
    });

    res.status(201).json(cv);
    console.log(req.body);
    // res.status(201).json({ body: req.body, file: req.file });
  });

export default createCV;

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // Disallow body parsing, consume as stream
  },
};
```

Again, if anyone knows how to do this without having to go outside of nextjs api routing system, I would sure appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT::**
I ran a debugger and got the following from the form values after submit in the useSubmit.js
[image]

This shows the value of cvfile as cv.docx which is correct but for the value of fileUrl (which is kind of important :) ) is set to undefined. Not good. And worse yet, because I am new to Next and a little green in this area, I don't know how to fix it.

**EDIT 2::**
On Debugger; my code dies after this block of code:

```
const response = await axios.post(API_URL, form, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata',
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read multiparty's README, I quote:

> Parse http requests with content-type **multipart/form-data**, also known as file uploads.

<sup>(I love the creative name of the package.)</sup> Your form needs to send data that's of `multipart/form-data` (you're using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (default value)).

In `useSubmitCV.js` alter the axios request to include the custom content type:

```js
// ...
await axios.post(API_URL, form, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata'
  }
});
```

This should allow multiparty to receive your data.

Comment: Thank you @code. I missed that. However, after implementing it, I am still getting ```{
  "error": "Sorry something Happened! Cannot destructure property 'firstName' of 'req.body' as it is undefined."
}```
Any clues? Thank you

Comment: @ErikJamesRobles in the `form.parse` callback try logging the value of `fields`; that'll help you debug.

Comment: I logged the value of fields where form.parse is located and I get all the fields input except the fileUrl which is:
```fileUrl: ['undefined'],```

Comment: @ErikJamesRobles it's probably something client-side; right before you send the request try logging the value of `fileUrl`; I would assume that's where you get `undefined` (you get undefined as a string, not as the primitive).

Comment: Thanks @code Not sure how I can do that since fileUrl doesn't get assigned until it is handled in the api route addcv as const fileUrl = req.file.filename; Forgive my ignorance if there is another way to do this. I am all ears.

Comment: So, @code, When I get to:
``` const cvSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      formData.firstName === '' ||
      formData.lastName === '' ||
      formData.email === '' ||
      formData.phone === ''
    ) {
      toast.error('All Fields are required');
    } else {
      debugger;
      console.log(formData.fileUrl);
      await submitcv(formData);
    }
    console.log(formData);
    setButtonClicked(!buttonClicked);
    setButtonText('Start Here');
  };```
I'm getting fileUrl as undefined which is my front end code. After that, the code breaks

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I had to simplify the multer and add file functionality. I removed the multiparty middleware and just stuck with nextConnect. Here is the revised code:

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
import connectDB from '../../../config/db';

import { File, Web3Storage } from 'web3.storage';

import CV from '../../../models/cvModel';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const w3storage = new Web3Storage({ token: process.env.WEB3_STORAGE_TOKEN });

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /doc|docx|pdf|odf/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb('Error: Documents Only!');
  }
}

const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
  fileFilter: function (_req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
});

const maxSize = 3 * 1000 * 1000;

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: maxSize } });

const createCV = nextConnect({
  onError(error, req, res) {
    res
      .status(501)
      .json({ error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}` });
  },
  onNoMatch(req, res) {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  },
})
  .use(upload.single('cvfile'))
  .post(async (req, res) => {
    // @desc Create a new cv
    // @route POST /api/cvs/addcv
    // @access Public
    await connectDB();

    try {
      const {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        phone,
        address,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        usEligible,
        dob,
        description,
      } = req.body;

      console.log(req.body, req.file);

      const newFile = new File([req.file.buffer], req.file.originalname);
      const cid = await w3storage.put([newFile]);

      const cv = await CV.create({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        phone,
        address,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        usEligible,
        dob,
        description,
        fileUrl: `https://${cid}.ipfs.dweb.link/${req.file.originalname}`,
      });

      return res.status(201).json(cv);

      // res.status(201).json({ body: req.body, file: req.file });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  });

export default createCV;
```

As you can see, since I am storing the files in web3 storage, there is no longer any need to use diskStorage so a lot of that code has been stripped out. I also removed the cvfile variable from this code as well as the model as it was not needed. I hope this helps anyone else having this particular issue.